# matplotlib & seaborn: how to get rid of lines?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm using the whitegrid style and it's fine except for the vertical lines in the background.

I just want to retain the horizontal lines.

Comment: what have you tried? might need to pass arguments into ax.yaxis.grid() or ax.xaxis.grid(), i.e 'True' or 'False'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing arguments into ax.yaxis.grid() and ax.xaxis.grid() will include or omit grids in the graphs